# office activation error

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, software-activation

Please help me activate my Office 2007 Home and Student Edition. I have the product key, but I don't see where to put it and haven't gotten the activation popup (see below):

[image]

- Trying the Internet option gives activation key invalid error and brings me back to screenshot
- Trying the telephone activation requires a confirmation code, which I don't have

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Also, if you are running Outlook, for example, you can click Help > Activate Product.  This should activate all the Office suite products.

Comment: Just wondering, is Office still sitting at the Activation screen, or did you figure out a solution?  :D

Answer (score 1):

After you select an activation method, it should ask you for a product key.

Comment: it doesnt ask.. instead gives an error that activation code supplied at time of installation is not correct. doesnt prompt to enter key

Answer (score 1):

You should pick "by telephone".

Comment: what should i put in confirmation code ? its a 36 character code

Answer (score 1):

Just click next.  If you entered the product key during installation, you won't need to enter it again.  If you haven't entered it, you'll eventually be prompted for it.